# Why empty compose activity not found in Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following the tutorial to learn Jetpack compose, but I'm stuck on the Empty-Compose-Activity template, I can't find this template.

Here is my Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.levinzonr.arch.jetpackcompose.plugin (0.5.0)
```

[image: My new project templates page]

I've tried searching this, but found nothing to solve this, please help

Comment: in new version of android studio the empty activity is the same as empty compose activity.

Comment: The second one ("Empty Activity") is just what you look for. It is a template using `Jetpack Compose` and `Material You` design. It was "Empty-Compose-Activity" and "Empty-Compose-Activity(M3)" in old version of AS.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I updated recently too and ran into the same issue

Apparently they redesigned the new project templates in  Flamingo | 2022.2.1

The "empty activity" will create a new empty material3 compose project, which should work the same as the "Empty-Compose-Activity" template. You can find more info in the [official release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i was really confused and thought i had to downgrade my android studio as i couldn't find the Jetpack option when creating new project.